# Poppup Modal Inside Fixed Position DIV appearing behind backdrop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I have a fixed position `<div>` that has the [summernote](http://summernote.org/#/) WYSIWYG nested inside of it. The problem is when I click the "link" button in the WYSIWYG it opens a Bootstrap Modal that appears behind the black backdrop.

Now the reason for this is the `<div>` that Summernote sits inside has a fixed position with a lower z-index than the backdrop. If I increase the z-index of the `<div>` than the background goes away because the entire `<div>` is moved on top of the backdrop.

Likewise I can't increase the z-index of the Summernote poppup as it is nested inside the conatiner `<div>` and inherits its z-index.

Here is a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmvs32vL/1/

Any ideas?

--- Edit 7/14/205 2:19PM ---

So my question is... is there any way to get the modal to appear in front of the backdrop with CSS? I can't move the modal without jquery and I'd rather not do that. The modal is created dynamically with summernote so I can't define it's position in the DOM.

Here is a video explaining this: http://screencast.com/t/Jz9o1rn7

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My personal idea is that you should explain better what you want to achieve.. If the problem is the z-index, set it manually... But in the fiddle I can't understand what are the three divs you are speaking about and what is the required behaviour/actual behaviour...

Comment: Yeah I added some clarification. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you didn't close out your container div properly.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="modal">Modal content</div>
  <div id="bg"></div>
</div>
```

This should fix it.

EDIT:
While your question is a little wordy... My understanding of the problem is that you were trying to move the "modal" above everything?

Comment: His container div is closed.

Comment: Yes, but I moved it after the #bg

Comment: Thanks. That would work but I don't have control over the modal's position in the DOM. See my updates. Thanks!

Comment: Try decreasing the z-index on #bg to 10; that seemed to make some changes on your fiddle example.